# Studying the convergence of an Euler sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to evaluate the series

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k+n}^2}{k+n}(-1)^{k+n}$$

*Where*

$$H_{k}^2=(H_k)^2=\left(\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}\right)^2$$

---

### Attempt

I am first concerned about convergence

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{k+n}^2}{k+n}(-1)^{k+n}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^2}{k}(-1)^k$$

Let $k+n = i$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{i=k}^\infty\frac{H_{i}^2}{i}(-1)^{i}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^2}{k}(-1)^k=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^i\frac{H_{i}^2}{i}(-1)^{i}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^2}{k}(-1)^k$$

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_{k}^2(-1)^{k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^2}{k}(-1)^k$$

The first diverges and the second converges hence I am tempted to say it diverges.

---

### Question

1. Is my method correct? I am concerened about interchanging the sums.
2. I am not concerned about evaluating the series as much as seeing the limiting behaviour of the partial sums, when I put it in W|A it says it diverges by the limit test but i cant trust that or can I ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let we consider the restricted sum
$$ T(N)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq a \leq N \\ 1\leq b \leq N \\ a+b\leq N}}\frac{H_{a+b}^2}{a+b}(-1)^{a+b} \tag{1}$$
By considering $a+b=m$ as a new summation variable, we get that:
$$ T(N) = \sum_{m=2}^{N}(-1)^m \frac{H_m^2}{m}\sum_{a=1}^{m-1}1 = \sum_{m=2}^{N}(-1)^m H_m^2\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right) \tag{2}$$
and $\lim_{N\to +\infty}T(N)$ does not exist, since the general term of the last series behaves like $\log^2(m)$ in absolute value, making $\sum_{m=2}^{+\infty}(-1)^m H_m^2 $ a non-convergent series.

Comment: The first notation seems strange for me. Is it used interchangeably with the one I posted ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: you considered a double series without knowing if it was convergent or if we were allowed to switch the sums. I just considered the partial sums "over large triangles" delimited by $1\leq a,b\leq N$ and $a+b\leq N$. They lead to a non-convergent series. You may use this result to prove that the partial sums "over squares" delimited by $1\leq a,b\leq N$ lead to a non convergent-series too, so we are doomed.